# Setting Nullable Integer to String Containing Nothing yields 0

Tags: .net, vb.net, nullable

I've been pulling my hair out over some unexpected behavior from nullable integers.

- If I set an `Integer` to `Nothing`, it becomes `Nothing` as expected.
- If I set an `Integer?` to a `String` that is `Nothing`, it becomes 0!

Of course I get this whether I explicitly cast the `String` to `Integer?` or not.

I realize I could work around this pretty easily but I want to know what I'm missing.

```
    Dim NullString As String = Nothing
    Dim NullableInt As Integer? = CType(NullString, Integer?) 'Expected NullableInt to be Nothing, but it's 0!
    NullableInt = Nothing 'This works, of course. NullableInt is Nothing.
```

**EDIT:** Previously I had my code up here so without the explicit conversion to `Integer?` and everyone seemed to be fixated on/confused by that. There were a lot of suggestions that Option Strict On would catch this type of thing. However, this is actually a quirk of the string-to-integer conversion rules which predate nullable types, but still impact them.

Comment: Use Option Strict On to catch these kind of mistakes early.

Comment: Why are you assigning a string variable to a Nullable INteger?  Agree on turning Option Strict On

Comment: You can turn on Option Strict one file at a time by placing Option Strict On.  That should let you deal with errors as you are working on the file.  It's definitely worth the effort in the long run

Comment: @Gideon Engelberth I actually didn't know you could do that page-level, thanks.

Comment: @BrianMacKay, I agree this behavior is very confusing regardless of the rationale behind it. Especially since an expression like `NullableInt = CType(Nothing, Integer?)` actually results in the desired `Nothing`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why has to do with the VB.Net conversion rules here.  The `String` type is incompatible with `Integer?` and hence an conversion takes place.  The intermediate step though is converting `String` to `Integer`.  The VB.Net conversion rules will convert a `Nothing` or empty `String` into the `Integer` value 0.  This can be reproduced without nullables

```
Dim local1 As String = Nothing
Dim local2 As Integer = local1 ' It's 0
```

This same conversion will then convert the `Integer` value 0 to the type `Integer?` which maintains the `Integer` value.

Comment: +1: Wow, so I seriously have to write my own little conversion for this? That seems like weak sauce.

Comment: @Brian MacKay: I would argue that interpreting the empty string `""` as a `Nullable(Of Integer)` with no value is pretty specific custom logic, and that you *should* have to write your own conversion if that's the behavior you want (the good news is that it's easy!). Just my two cents.

Comment: @Dan Tao: But the string is not String.Empty, it's Null.

Comment: @Brian yes but VB.Net had an existing narrowing conversion from `String` to `Integer` even when the `String` was `Nothing` before nullables came around.  This behavior is just a side effect of the rule that allows for a conversion from X -> Y? when there is already a conversion from X -> Y and Y is a value type.

Answer (score 0):

WHY are you trying to assign a string to an integer????

```
    Dim nullInt As Nullable(Of Integer) 'nullInt = Nothing as expected

    'the following should NOT compile and won't with Option Strict On

    nullInt = ""
    nullInt = String.Empty
```